# Formating time and date with R

Tags: r, datetime-format, lubridate, posixct

I am trying to change a date into a hms timestamp.  I use `lubridate`´s `ymd_hms` function.  I tried to ways that I show below.  In both cases I lose the hms format.

```
require(lubridate)
dt <- "2009-12-03"  
dt <- paste(dt, c(" 00:00:00"))
dt <- ymd_hms(dt)
dt
[1] "2009-12-03 UTC"
```

I was expecting to see "2009-12-03 00:00:00".  The second example is:

```
dt <- "2009-12-03"
dt <-as.POSIXct(ymd_hms(paste(dt, c(" 00:00:00"))), tz="UTC", format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))
dt
[1] NA NA
```

Hopefully its a stupid mistake that I am doing....  Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is inside *trades*?

Comment: Since there is nothing to show or process when the hms part is `"00:00:00"`, it is discarded. Try `dt <- paste(dt, c("00:00:00.1"))
`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas note 00:00:00 will be displayed if there are multiple elements of the vector and some elements HMS time is not 00:00:00

Comment: For example, try `dt <- c("2009-12-03", "2009-12-04");
dt <- paste(dt, c("00:00:00", "00:00:01"));
dt <- ymd_hms(dt);
dt`

Comment: Though I would say, that @RuiBarradas solution is the best to get your date displayed if you want them to all have the same HMS stamp

Comment: @duckmayr True, I was testing the code with the data provided and forgot that.